# Cannot reproduce result of Type Erasure example

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I am reading 'Java Generics and Collections' section 8.4. The author defines the following code while trying to explain Binary Compatibility:

```
interface Name extends Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Object o);
}
class SimpleName implements Name {
    private String base;
    public SimpleName(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return base.compareTo(((SimpleName)o).base);
    }
}
class ExtendedName extends SimpleName {
    private String ext;
    public ExtendedName(String base, String ext) {
        super(base); this.ext = ext;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        int c = super.compareTo(o);
        if (c == 0 && o instanceof ExtendedName)
        return ext.compareTo(((ExtendedName)o).ext);
        else
        return c;
    }
}
class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name m = new ExtendedName("a","b");
        Name n = new ExtendedName("a","c");
        assert m.compareTo(n) < 0;
    }
}
```

and then talks about making the Name interface and SimpleName class generic and leaving the ExtendedName as is. As a result the new code is:

```
interface Name extends Comparable<Name> {
    public int compareTo(Name o);
}
class SimpleName implements Name {
    private String base;
    public SimpleName(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    public int compareTo(Name o) {
        return base.compareTo(((SimpleName)o).base);
    }
}
// use legacy class file for ExtendedName
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name m = new ExtendedName("a","b");
        Name n = new ExtendedName("a","c");
        assert m.compareTo(n) == 0; // answer is now different!
    }
}
```

The author describes the result of such an action as following:

> Say that we generify Name and SimpleName so that they define
>   compareTo(Name), but that we do not have the source for ExtendedName. Since it defines
>   only compareTo(Object), client code that calls compareTo(Name) rather than compareTo(Object) will invoke the method on SimpleName (where it is defined) rather than
>   ExtendedName (where it is not defined), so the base names will be compared but the
>   extensions ignored.

However when I make only Name and SimpleName generic I get a compile time error and not what the author describes above. The error is:

> name clash: compareTo(Object) in NameHalfMovedToGenerics.ExtendedName and compareTo(T) in Comparable have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

And this is not the first time I am facing such an issue - earlier while trying to read Sun documentation on erasure I faced a similar issue where my code doesn't show the same result as described by the author.

Have I made a mistake in understanding what the author is trying to say?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code in which you "*make only Name and SimpleName generic*".

Comment: I already have - in the second code block above. Are you asking for something else? 1. Comparable is converted to Comparable<Name> and 2. In SimpleName class the method compareTo(Object) becomes compareTo(Name).

Comment: Did you make the source for `ExtendedName` unavailable as the author implied?

Comment: No I didn't. I have Name, SimpleName and ExtendedName all as inner classes of my main class. So you mean I just keep the .class file for ExtendedName and rewrite the generics equivalent for the rest of the classes, right?

Comment: @Mustafa Yes, this is what the author meant.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks. Let me try that. I might have learned something new after your explanation. I will post my result soon.

Comment: @Mustafa Maybe you must also do that for the `Test` class containing `main()`

Comment: @Micheal I am trying to do what you said and I am struggling. I will figure out what needs to be done to achieve this and get back. Right now I copied the class files to a temp directory, deleted the source files for ExtendedName and the Test class and copied back their old class files to the build location and trying to run the Test class via command prompt and it's failing. I am anyway going to +1 your suggestion as I had completely missed that part.

Comment: @Micheal - I managed to delete the source files as you said and ran the program again. And to my surprise - compareTo(Object) from ExtendedName is still being called and I am getting the same result as the legacy version. I am not at all sure how. I am trying to figure that out now.

Comment: Maybe the book refers to a different Java VM version and yours behaves differently (but actually I doubt that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a problem that can occur under **separate compilation**.

The main subtlety with separate compilation is that, when a caller class is compiled, certain information is copied from the callee into the caller's class file. If the caller is later run against a different version of the callee, the information copied from the old version of the callee might not match exactly the new version of the callee, and the results might be different. This is very hard to see by just looking at source code. This example shows how the behavior of a program can change in a surprising way when such a modification is made.

In the example, `Name` and `SimpleName` were modified and recompiled, but the old, compiled binary of `ExtendedName` is still used. That's really what it means by "the source code for `ExtendedName` is not available." When a program is compiled against the modified class hierarchy, it records different information than it would have if it were compiled against the old hierarchy.

Let me run through the steps I performed to reproduce this example.

In an empty directory, I created two subdirectories `v1` and `v2`. In `v1` I put the classes from the first example code block into separate files `Name.java`, `SimpleName.java`, and `ExtendedName.java`.

Note that I'm not using the `v1` and `v2` directories as packages. All these files are in the unnamed package. Also, I'm using separate files, since if they're all nested classes it's hard to recompile some of them separately, which is necessary for the example to work.

In addition I renamed the main program to `Test1.java` and modified it as follows:

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name m = new ExtendedName("a","b");
        Name n = new ExtendedName("a","c");
        System.out.println(m.compareTo(n));
    }
}
```

In `v1` I compiled everything and ran Test1:

```
$ ls
ExtendedName.java  Name.java  SimpleName.java  Test1.java
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ javac *.java
$ java Test1
-1
```

Now, in `v2` I placed the `Name.java` and `SimpleName.java` files, modified using generics as shown in the second example code block. I also copied in `v1/Test1.java` to `v2/Test2.java` and renamed the class accordingly, but otherwise the code is the same.

```
$ ls
Name.java  SimpleName.java  Test2.java
$ javac -cp ../v1 *.java
$ java -cp .:../v1 Test2
0
```

This shows that the result of `m.compareTo(n)` is different after `Name` and `SimpleName` were modified, while using the old `ExtendedName` binary. What happened?

We can see the difference by looking at the disassembled output from the `Test1` class (compiled against the old classes) and the `Test2` class (compiled against the new classes) to see what bytecode is generated for the `m.compareTo(n)` call. Still in `v2`:

```
$ javap -c -cp ../v1 Test1
...
29: invokeinterface #8,  2     // InterfaceMethod Name.compareTo:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
...

$ javap -c Test2
...
29: invokeinterface #8,  2     // InterfaceMethod Name.compareTo:(LName;)I
...
```

When compiling `Test1`, the information copied into the `Test1.class` file is a call to `compareTo(Object)` because that's the method the `Name` interface has at this point. With the modified classes, compiling `Test2` results in bytecode that calls `compareTo(Name)` since that's what the modified `Name` interface now has. When `Test2` runs, it looks for the `compareTo(Name)` method and thus **bypasses** the `compareTo(Object)` method in the `ExtendedName` class, calling `SimpleName.compareTo(Name)` instead. That's why the behavior differs.

Note that the behavior of the old `Test1` **binary** does not change:

```
$ java -cp .:../v1 Test1
-1
```

But if `Test1.java` were recompiled against the new class hierarchy, its behavior would change. That's essentially what `Test2.java` is, but with a different name so that we can easily see the difference between running an old binary and a recompiled version.

Comment: I would go to the mountains having given everything else up to learn java if someone told me I could be like you. Thanks man, you are awesome. I reproduced the issue successfully now I am wondering if I should try to understand the minor details of everything you said above but I will move ahead with some other simpler topics that I don't know and come back to this a little later. But you did the job man ! Thanks

Comment: You flatter me. Truly I am not an expert. (Consider the guys who wrote that book, for example.) But thanks, I'm glad I helped. Make sure to learn a little bit every day, and keep it up over a long time.